# Difference between ESLint and TSLint

Tags: reactjs, angular, typescript

I searched for many articles about this question. I couldn't find any article related to that. Can some tell me what are the cons of **Eslint** over **TsLint**. Why do we have to move to **ESLint**?

Comment: TsLint is also deprecated as of 2019: https://medium.com/palantir/tslint-in-2019-1a144c2317a9. Eslint can perform linting for TypeScript :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Edit 1 ( NOV 2021 )**

Currently, I am using `EsLint` in TypeScript, and I loved it. I suggest do not use `TsLint` because it's deprecated and `EsLint` have more linting features than `TsLint`.

**Original**

`TsLint` is spacially made for `TypeScript` and `EsLint` can use in both side `JavaScript` and `TypeScript` but its standard way to use `TsLint` in `TypeScript` because its have better linting and type checking then `EsLint` in `TypeScript`

There is no comparison here, pros and cons are checked when you are comparing any similar things but here both are different

check that article: https://codeburst.io/from-eslint-to-tslint-and-back-again-bf259c2e7437

Answer (score 19):

**TSLint** can only be used for **TypeScript**, while **ESLint** supports both **JavaScript** and **TypeScript**. It is likely, within a large project that you may use both **JavaScript** and **TypeScript**.

Comment: We literally posted the same comment within a minute of each other, apologies I never saw yours.